# Lightweight Flash Video Recording Server

Tags: flash, video-capture, rtmp, video-recording

I am currently using Wowza Media server for recording videos from webcam using Flash. However servers like Wowza, Red5 & Flash Media Server seem to be overkill for merely this task.

Are there any alternative lightweight video recording servers which can be used for the purpose? My load would not be more than 5 users at a time and my server is Ubuntu 8.04.

I tried Haxe Server but project seems to be outdated and won't compile on my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about projects like Red5 is that you can strip them down to fit your need. We are componentizing Red5 for version 1.0; I'll keep your case in mind.